# Eclipse autocomplete not working for some source files

Tags: java, linux, eclipse

After I upgraded from my old Eclipse (something from 2019... don't know anymore) to Eclipse "2021-06 (4.20.0)" (Current Build id: 20210612-2011) I'm facing real problems with autocomplete. For **some** files (not all!) this feature totally screw up. If I press CRTL+space I only see Classes and templates but no java types. If I type in the variable by my own and pressing "." (for example `exampleVariable.`) normally Eclipse would show all possible methods and such but now nothing happens. It is like if Eclipse don't see this "exampleVariable" in my code. But if I complete the whole term to lets say `exampleVariable.exampleMethod();` eclipse don't underline it with red lines and if I hover with the mouse I can see the javadoc. If I then delete the `.exampleMethod();` and try again starting with the dot - nothing happens again... Eclipse behaves like a dump text editor!

And this only happens for specific source files. If I open another source file all is working as expected. I can close and reopen my project, the affected source file or even the whole eclipse as often as I want - nothing changes..

This really is a problem for me as I can't work in this situation.

Answer (score 3):

Open the menu
Window->Preferences->Java->Editor->Content Assist->Advanced.
Now make sure the following are all ticked in the top and bottom sections:
Java Non-Type Proposals
Java Proposals
Java Type Proposals
Apply the changes and then close and re-open your project and it will build the autocompletion which will then become available when you hit Ctrl-Space.

I hope this will fix the issue.